# Raster Published as Tile Layer Not Displaying on AGOL

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, arcgis-online, web

I have a raster layer given to me by a colleague. I was able to successfully publish and view it on ArcGIS Online as a tile layer, but now I'm trying to resample it to reduce the size and am starting to see some weird behavior - not only am I not able to successfully view a resampled version, I'm unable to re-publish the original tile layer. Here's the information I've collected so far:

1. The original layer shows up correctly when I add it as a weblayer set to cache on the server.

   It shows up in a gray box when I look at the tile layer or the service definition on ArcGIS Online.

   It's 43 MB as a tile layer, 102 MB as a service definition. Its visible range was set by default to state-metropolitan area
2. When I use the resample tool to resize the raster pixel size from 30m to 50m and then publish as a web layer, it publishes without errors but does not show up when I view it with MapViewer (new or classic).

   It does not show up in a gray box when I look at the tile layer or the service definition on ArcGIS Online.

   It's 6MB. Its visible range is set by default to state-metropolitan area.
3. When I re-upload the original layer, it also publishes without errors but does not show up correctly when I view it with MapViewer.

   It does not show up in a gray box when I look at the tile layer or the service definition.

   It's the same size as the original as a service definition, 102 MB. It's only 21 MB as a tile layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to my supervisor who ended up helping me out with this.

The issue was the projection. ArcGIS Online's default basemaps use the Web Mercator 1984 projection. My raster layers were using USA Contiguous Albers. Once I used the Project Raster tool to change the projection and re-uploaded the layers, they were all visible using Map Viewer as expected, and show up inside a gray bounding box in the thumbnail.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I tried two methods and both worked:

1. Reprojecting my raster to "WGS 1984 Web Mercator (auxiliary sphere)" and then publishing it as a tile layer. This did work; however, the reprojection was extremely time consuming.
2. I inserted a "New Map", changed its Coordinate System (in Properties) to "WGS 1984 Web Mercator (auxiliary sphere)" a.k.a WMAS.

Ensure you select the Map with WMAS projection (refer to the screenshot).[image: screenshot]